# How to arrange/group by specific id

Tags: angular

I would like to know how to achieve this. Basically I'm supposed to show this data into a profile. The idea is to show the `advocacy` as a heading, and the `particular_interest` will be listed below the `advocacy`

so it's something like:

Advocacy 1
Particular Interest 1
Particular Interest 2
Particular Interest 3

Advocacy 2
Particular Interest 4
Particular Interest 5

Advocacy 3
Particular Interest 6

The problem is the data I have is this:

```
data = [{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 67,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 1',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 68,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 2',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 69,
  particular_interes: 'particular interest 3',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 70,
  particular_interes: 'particular interest 4',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 70,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 4',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 71,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 5',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '4', advocacy: 'Advocacy 3'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '4',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 72,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 6',
}]
```

so I would very much appreciate to know how to group the `particular_interest` per `advocacy`. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a combination of the `reduce` array function and the `Map` object.

```js
const data = [{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 67,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 1',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 68,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 2',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 69,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 3',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 70,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 4',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 70,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 4',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 71,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 5',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '4', advocacy: 'Advocacy 3'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '4',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 72,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 6',
}];

// create a map to store unique advocacy groups
const map = new Map();

// use "reduce" to loop through each item in data and create an array of advocacy groups
const grouped = data.reduce((arr, current) => {
  const advocacy = current.admin_advocacy.advocacy;
  // find the previously created group
  let group = map.get(advocacy); 
  if (!group) {
    // no previously created group - create a new one
    group = {
      advocacy: advocacy,
      interests: []
    };
    
    // add the group to the map and the return array
    map.set(current.admin_advocacy.advocacy, group);         
    arr.push(group);
  }
  
  // only add unique interests to the group
  if (!group.interests.some(x => x.id === current.id)) {
    group.interests.push({
      id: current.id,
      particular_interest: current.particular_interest
    });
  }
  
  // return the array to the next iteration
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: hi, I'm currently tryng this solution. Thank you very much for this, can I make the interest into an object? and within that could I also put the id and particular_interest as key?

this is from what I imagine:

{
    "advocacy": "Advocacy 1",
    "interests": [
       { 
          id: 67,
          particular_interest: "particular interest 1"
       },
       { 
          id: 68
          particular_interest: "particular interest 2"
       },
       { 
          id: 69,
          particular_interest: "particular interest 3"
       },
      
    ]
  },

Comment: Yes - code updated. I have assumed that id is the unique key when checking for existing interests.

Comment: It's working now! Thank you very much sir for dedicating the time to help me. Hope you and your family are doing well and safe during these times!

Answer (score 1):

```
 mapArray() {
    const groupBy = (array, key) => {
      // Return the end result
      return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
        // If an array already present for key, push it to the array. Else create an array and push the object
        (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
          currentValue
        );

        if (!result[currentValue[key]]) {
          result[currentValue[key]] = [];
        }
        result[currentValue[key]].push(currentValue);
        // Return the current iteration `result` value, this will be taken as next iteration `result` value and accumulate
        return result;
      }, {}); // empty object is the initial value for result object
    };

    // Group by color as key to the person array
    const personGroupedByColor = groupBy(this.data, 'admin_advocacy_id');
    console.log(personGroupedByColor);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of your `particular_interest` in your JSON is `particular_interes`, I assume it's a typo and replate it with `particular_interest`. And there is a dupilcated item under `Advocacy 2`, I kept it.

My approch is using reduce.

```js
data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    curAdvocacy = cur['admin_advocacy']['advocacy']
    acc[curAdvocacy] = acc[curAdvocacy] || []
    acc[curAdvocacy].push(cur['particular_interest'])
    return acc
  }, {})
```

```js
data = [{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 67,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 1',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 68,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 2',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '2', advocacy: 'Advocacy 1' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '2',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 69,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 3',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2' },
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 70,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 4',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 70,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 4',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '3', advocacy: 'Advocacy 2'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '3',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 71,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 5',
},
{
  admin_advocacy: { id: '4', advocacy: 'Advocacy 3'},
  admin_advocacy_id: '4',
  donor_id: 14,
  id: 72,
  particular_interest: 'particular interest 6',
}]

function group(data) {
  return data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    curAdvocacy = cur['admin_advocacy']['advocacy']
    acc[curAdvocacy] = acc[curAdvocacy] || []
    acc[curAdvocacy].push(cur['particular_interest'])
    return acc
  }, {})

}


document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(group(data), undefined, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just by a `loop`, you can group it.

```
 const obj = {};

 data.forEach(item => {
    let key = item.admin_advocacy.advocacy;    
    obj[key] = obj[key] || {};
    obj[key].interest = obj[key].interest || [];
    obj[key].interest.push(item.particular_interest);
 });

 console.log(obj);
```

It will return you an object with grouping interest. See below:

```
{
  "Advocacy 1": {
    "interest": ["particular interest 1", "particular interest 2", "particular interest 3"]
 },
  "Advocacy 2": {
    "interest": ["particular interest 4", "particular interest 5"]
 }
  "Advocacy 3": {
    "interest": ["particular interest 6"]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Component

```
this.result = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        const currAdv = curr.admin_advocacy.advocacy;
        prev[currAdv] = prev[currAdv] || [];
        prev[currAdv].push(curr.particular_interest);
        return prev;
    }, {});
```

#### HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of result | keyvalue">
        <h3>{{ item.key }}</h3>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let i of item.value">
                {{ i }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image]